# Microsoft Teams: EntityId of a config tab - Limit and risks to use it as a object storage

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have a requirement to cache the Tab data. I dont want to use external storage as I have to manage the security myself and I dont want to use Teams SharePoint Site or User's onedrive becuase of lots of scenario(Teams/group/delete/modify) and extra graph permission.

As a solution I fugure out that I can pass my whole object in Entity Id, while configuring the page and access it in the Pinned tab from Teams Context.

My concern is, I see that Entity Id is a string type with no limit of charcters. As name says its an Id, am I misusing it?

The Entity Id of a Static Page, I see there is a limit of 64 charcters as specified in app manifest file schema. But for Entity Id of config page, I dont see such limit. Does microsoft forgot to put a limit or it is intentionaly left for developer to define what suits for there app purpose. Please confirm.

This is how I am setting up the config tab: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea at all - the purpose of this EntityId is to support Deep Linking - see more at https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/how-to/preview-with-cloudflare-tunnel/  I would not advise using it for other things. What you can do instead is pass querystring parameters - these are configured once when the tab is added to the channel / chat and can be reconfigured any time the user opens the Settings page for the tab.

Comment: Yeah, but querystring parameters also has a limit. The object I want to save is really big. It also has a image binary. So I coudnt use the content url or website url. Is there any other property which I can use for this purpose and can access back from Teams context like a property bag?

Comment: no, no property bag or anything like that. Maybe Azure Blob storage could work for you